# Websocket connection error with HiveMQ 2.1.0 + Paho javascript mqttws31.js

Tags: websocket, hivemq

Hi I am using Hivemq (windows) too and have an issue !

websocket are open and I receive some information:

```
2017-01-19 11:05:27,065 INFO  - Starting HiveMQ Server
2017-01-19 11:05:27,070 INFO  - HiveMQ version: 3.2.1
2017-01-19 11:05:27,074 INFO  - HiveMQ home directory: C:\hivemq-3.2.1
2017-01-19 11:05:27,115 INFO  - Log Configuration was overridden by C:\hivemq-3.2.1\conf\logback.xml
2017-01-19 11:05:31,533 INFO  - Loaded Plugin HiveMQ JMX Metrics Reporting Plugin - v3.0.0
2017-01-19 11:05:31,534 INFO  - Loaded Plugin HiveMQ JVM Metrics Plugin - v3.1.0
2017-01-19 11:05:31,535 INFO  - Loaded Plugin HiveMQ MQTT Message Log Plugin - v3.0.0
2017-01-19 11:05:31,551 INFO  - JMX Metrics Reporting started.
2017-01-19 11:05:31,574 INFO  - Starting TCP listener on address 127.0.0.1 and port 1883
2017-01-19 11:05:31,701 INFO  - Starting Websocket listener on address 127.0.0.1 and port 9001
2017-01-19 11:05:31,705 INFO  - Started TCP Listener on address 127.0.0.1 and on port 1883
2017-01-19 11:05:31,706 INFO  - Started Websocket Listener on address 127.0.0.1 and on port 9001
2017-01-19 11:05:31,707 INFO  - Started HiveMQ in 4637ms
2017-01-19 11:05:31,708 INFO  - No valid license file found. Using evaluation license, restricted to 25 connections.
2017-01-19 11:05:46,058 INFO  - Client mosq/@IL\R8\7_1OBQj3hs@ connected
2017-01-19 11:05:46,138 INFO  - Subscribe from client mosq/@IL\R8\7_1OBQj3hs@ received: domoticz/in QoS: 0
2017-01-19 11:05:49,867 INFO  - Client mosq/@IL\R8\7_1OBQj3hs@ sent a message to topic "domoticz/out": "{
   "Battery" : 100,
   "RSSI" : 7,
   "description" : "",
   "dtype" : "Temp + Humidity",
   "id" : "62721",
   "idx" : 3,
   "name" : "bureau",
   "nvalue" : 0,
   "stype" : "THGN122/123, THGN132, THGR122/228/238/268",
   "svalue1" : "19.0",
   "svalue2" : "34",
   "svalue3" : "2",
   "unit" : 1
}
" (QoS: 0, retained: false)
2017-01-19 11:06:05,761 INFO  - Client mosq/@IL\R8\7_1OBQj3hs@ sent a message to topic "domoticz/out": "{
   "Battery" : 100,
   "RSSI" : 7,
   "description" : "",
   "dtype" : "Temp + Humidity",`enter code here
`
```

but i always have issue in chrome console :

```
`WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:9001/' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response
k._doConnect @ mqttws31-min.js:36
k._disconnected @ mqttws31-min.js:54
k._on_socket_error @ mqttws31-min.js:51
(anonymous) @ mqttws31-min.js:19e
```

i am not a specialist please help

Answer (score 4):

According to the Eclipse Paho [Wiki](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Paho/Paho_Websockets)

> The path portion of the url specified on the MQTT connect should be "mqtt" 
>   For instance ws://m2m.eclipse.org:800/mqtt . mqtt should be the default with the option for an alternative to be configured / specified

However the default path used by paho javascript is "/ws"

HiveMQ uses default configuration of "/mqtt" for websocket's path

Possible solutions are

- Change path in Client to "/mqtt"

  ```
  client = new Paho.MQTT.Client("127.0.0.1", Number(9001), "/mqtt", "clientId");
  ```
- Change path in HiveMQ config to "/ws"

  ```
  <websocket-listener>
  ...
    <path>/ws</path>
  ...
    </websocket-listener>
  ```

Regards,

Florian, from the HiveMQ Team.